# How to delete document by _id using quickmongo [MongoDB]?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I've been trying for an hour, searching everywhere, and i've found no solution.

Comment: don't mind me, but before you download a npm package, check their weekly downloads. This package is being downloaded at only 1,410/week, which means very very few people are using it. Most people will use Mongoose orm with Mongodb, which is not exactly any harder than quickmongo

Answer (score 2):

To delete by _id, use remove() in MongoDB. Following is the syntax −

```js
db.yourCollectionName.remove({_id:yourObjectId});
```